# Saving / Exporting File in objective-c which I can then open in Ruby

Tags: objective-c, ruby, database, cocoa, avaudioplayer

I am an absolute beginner, so I am sorry if this question has been asked before and I simply couldnt find it because I was lacking the right search terms. Feel free to point me to the right posts and delete this one her. So apologies in advance.

I am looking to program a software that imports a list and links every word or sentence on that list to an audio file. I then want to export the whole thing: the list, the audio files AND how the relations between the words in order to use everything with a different app, programmed in a different programming (that is all yet to come. it will probably be in ruby)

Since I will probably not be able to open coredata files with ruby, which file format will be the best for me, so that I can use it in ruby etc.? or will I have to save all audio files individually, *as* audio files and have a separate txt file that links the words to the files? This sounds... wrong? :(

Sorry I am so lost right now!

Answer (score 0):

You can use json file to hold all your data. It is widely accepted as a data interchange format. But better not to embed audio files in another file. Instead you can save path to you audio file.

Comment: thank you! so i would use json to save the Strings etc. and the paths to the audios and save the audios separately? And if I want to upload it to my ruby server, I will have to select all the audio files individually or is there any way to package them maybe? thanks again for your answer!

Comment: Yes that is an idea. If you absolutely have to keep json and audio files together you can use tar or zip file as a container.